# How do I change the default color (#267114) of region when I use only one parameter Country in geochart

Tags: php, google-visualization

I use a geochart same like this link 
jsfiddle.net
code .
I use only one parameter City or country for data-set in geochart , I am unable to change his default data fill region color .

I want to change only circle color they are currently #267114 some thing like green .

Comment: Please note that all the required information to understand and answer this question is only in your mind...

Answer (score 0):

Better you can give the full information (OR) Check with this site,
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Answer (score 0):

`var options = {
    defaultColor: '#F9CB1C'
}`

It's not in the documentation for some reason. #hth